# Issue sorting files in a folder "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I am trying to read and sort the file names of a folder "frames", but I´m getting the error. My code is as follows:

```
col_frames = os.listdir(path + 'frames/')

# sort file names
col_frames.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f)))

# empty list to store the frames
col_images=[]

for i in col_frames:
    # read the frames
    img = cv2.imread(path + 'frames/'+i)
    # append the frames to the list
    col_images.append(img)
```

And I´m getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6300f903ade1> in <module>
      6 
      7 # sort file names
----> 8 col_frames.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f)))
      9 
     10 # empty list to store the frames

<ipython-input-17-6300f903ade1> in <lambda>(f)
      6 
      7 # sort file names
----> 8 col_frames.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f)))
      9 
     10 # empty list to store the frames

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I do net to convert that to integers. Can you explain me what´s going on and if there is a way around?

While printing `print(col_frames)` I get this: `['348.png', '1186.png', '412.png', '374.png', '360.png', '406.png', '1192.png', '1179.png', '1145.png', '1623.png', '1637.png', '1151.png', '638.png', '176.png', '88.png', '610.png', '1384.png', '1390.png', '604.png', '162.png', '189.png', '837.png', '77.png', '823.png', '63.png', '1409.png', '1421.png', '1347.png', '1353.png', '1435.png', '980.png', '758.png', '994.png', '1596.png', '764.png', '770.png', '1582.png', '1569.png', '943.png',....]`

Comment: What file path triggers this error?

Comment: Sounds like one of your files doesn't contain any digits in its name...

Comment: add a `print(col_frames)` to your script and post the ouput

Comment: @frederic this is the output: ['348.png', '1186.png', '412.png', '374.png', '360.png', '406.png', '1192.png', '1179.png', '1145.png', '1623.png', '1637.png', '1151.png', '638.png', '176.png', '88.png', '610.png', '1384.png', '1390.png', '604.png', '162.png', '189.png', '837.png'...

Comment: @CrazyChucky these are the frame names "@frederic this is the output: ['348.png', '1186.png', '412.png', '374.png', '360.png', '406.png', '1192.png', '1179.png', '1145.png', '1623.png', '1637.png', '1151.png', '638.png', '176.png', '88.png', '610.png', '1384.png', '1390.png', '604.png', '162.png', '189.png', '837.png'...

Comment: @frederic I posted the output of print(col_frames)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your list of files there is at least one filename which does not contain a number. To fix this, either remove these files, or rename them to contain a number, or add following to your code **before** the line that produces the error:

```py
for filename in col_frames:
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in filename): # check if there is any number in the filename
        col_frames.pop(filename) # else remove it from the file list
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause is that at least one item in the directory *doesn't have any digits in its name*. I can think of two main reasons this could happen:

1. The directory contains one or more items other than your images. They might be subdirectories, other random files, or, more likely, hidden files used by the operating system, such as `.DS_Store` on macOS.
2. One or more of your images is not named the way you expect your images to be named.

First, let's assume #1. Here is code that will examine only .png images, using Python's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which handles paths [more conveniently (and generally more robustly)](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) than `os`, with no worrying about proper OS-dependent separators, trailing slashes, etc. Though admittedly it's annoying that python-cv2 doesn't fully support it yet.

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Presumably your base path is defined above as a string. Here we make a Path
# object out of it.
path = Path(path)

# Get all *.png files 
frame_files = (path / 'frames').glob('*.png')

# Sort file names by the filename (minus extension) as an int
frame_files.sort(key=lambda f: int(f.stem))

# Build list
frames = [cv2.imread(str(path / 'frames' / frame_file))
          for frame_file in frame_files]
```

I changed the last part to a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/), but you could also keep it as a for loop if you find that more readable:

```py
frames = []
for frame_file in frame_files:
    frames.append(cv2.imread(str(path / 'frames' / frame_file)))
```

If this throws the same error, then you know at least one of your frame image files has a malformed filename. You could find it/them with:

```py
for frame_file in frame_files:
    if not frame_file.stem.isdigit():
        print(frame_file)
```

---

The only reason you need `cv2.imread(str(path / 'frames' / frame_file))` (or perhaps `cv2.imread(str(frame_file.resolve())`, YMMV) is because python-cv2 [doesn't yet fully support Path objects](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15731) the way native Python tools like `open()` do. If and when that's improved, you'd be able to do simply `cv2.imread(frame_file)`, because each Path object isn't just a string; it already knows where it's located.

I added a comment about this very fact to that Github issue, to add one more voice in support.